# Mysql How to outfile in csv format, with sheets options?

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv, select-into-outfile

I want to export data from mysql into a csv. There are many tables so I want a csv file with many sheets. How it can be done?

I suppose somethings like:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE active = 1
INTO OUTFILE '/root/tmp/data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

SELECT *
FROM member
WHERE active = 1
INTO OUTFILE '/root/tmp/data.csv' // using the same .csv
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot append to an existing file using `INTO OUTFILE`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html says:

> **file_name** cannot be an existing file, which among other things prevents files such as `/etc/passwd` and database tables from being destroyed.

So you'll have to output to a different file per table, and then concatenate them together yourself (that is, not using SQL).